# Как заменить слова при авторизации

Tags: php

```
<div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#sign_in">Sign in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Чтоб при авторизации,выводился email вместо sign in, когда пользователь авторизировался

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['email'];
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="#sign_in"><?= isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : 'Sign in' ?></a></li>
```

Comment: точнее не менялось, а надо чтоб выводился email вместо sign in, когда пользователь авторизировался

Comment: ну это оно и есть ))) если в сессии есть email то он выводится, если нет то Sign In